# What is flag status pending in my list of flagged posts?

Tags: support, flag-history

I flagged some posts this morning. Looking now in the helpful flags from my profile I see that one of them is `pending`. Also another flag, from early February, which this morning was `active` is now `pending`.

I've never seen pending before. I've done some searching, and although outstanding active flags are routinely referred to as pending, I can't find any mention of flags which actually say pending. I've also searched in the help. No luck. What does pending mean as a flag status?

[image: Example of pending]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pending seems to be the new active.

Perhaps "active" suggested more urgency than was really intended.

When I think of "active" I tend to think "Oh, they're working on it now...", as opposed to "pending" which seems to say "They'll get around to it..."

Just speculation, but I doubt the change in language signifies any change in function.

Comment: Seems to check out. I did wonder about a custom flag of mine being active for two months, wondering how many high-level meetings were being held on it each week. However, just flagged another NAA and he say pending. Takes away all the drama and expectation :-)

Comment: Bikeshedding: I would have gone with "queued", because anyone who's queued for something (aka "waited in line") knows what it means, even before the programming meaning and our own review queues.  (It's even technically accurate for close, NAA and VLQ flags, which go to the queues.)

Comment: +1 Based on my analysis of users' flagging histories, it does seem to be nothing more than a simple rename. (Man it feels good to not have my +1 comments restricted this way.)

Answer (score 39):

I take full credit or blame for this one. While we've been knee-deep in translations, a few rather ambiguous strings have been catching our attention, and this was one of them. Nothing changed with your flags – it was a simple copy change.

Three sites translated this incorrectly, and the very same day I realized we'd have to go back and change all instances of it, someone that *works here* came to me to ask what 'active' meant. It was confusing. We used 'pending' because it better describes the state of the thing it applies to, in context.

Other minor changes you probably won't even see are 'left' -> 'available' when talking about a quantity of something, and a few others where the English itself  could be more deliberately stated.

Sorry for the confusion! I don't think there will be any more of these, but if any looked major or potentially confusing, I'll post a self-answered question to clear up any confusion.

Comment: Thanks. You know those little blocks of stuff to the right on the same page. Where is says `declined` and a count and `disputed` and a count, and matches the text in the list? Any chance that the other two could become `pending` and `helpful`?

Comment: And documentation in the help centre....

Comment: And what is the status "aged away" mean as well?

Comment: "pending" is **way** better than "active", nice one.

Comment: "I'll post a self-answered question to clear up any confusion." inb4 "Recent change to the wording of stuff... the cheese is still there!"

Comment: I'm going to update all the things related to this at some point tomorrow or this weekend. Thanks to all that pointed out there was more to do :) (Ooooopsie) Geez, you change _one_ word ...